# Showing True False as red/green

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below I am fetching the "status" data "true/false",from the database and adding the data to a list called List1. What I am trying to achieve is that if a value is `true` then the colour of the cell should be red. How do I achieve that?

```
List<Details> List1 = new List<Detail>();
foreach (var item in xyz)
{
      staus = bsCls.GetStatus(xy,uw,yx);

      if (staus != null)
      {
          List1.Add(staus);//here i need to change
      }
}

if (staus != null)
{
      dates.DataSource = List1;
      dates.DataBind();
      e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(dates);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to find the cell of that grid and do coding as below :-

```
GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
```

Answer (score 0):

USe Grid.RowDataBound control and there based on bound value for True/False, hide or show the red color image or blue colr image in Grid Column.. See if this helps http://forums.asp.net/t/1555748.aspx?How+to+display+image+in+gridview+according+to+Condition

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     //check for true/false of datarow column value
     if (Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "List1.CloumnName")) == "True")
     {
         e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
     }
     else
     {
         e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
     }
}
```

Comment: I am getting databinding property error from "List1.CloumnName"

Comment: can you just update you question with Details class information.

Comment: I am sorry but i cant put that here

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add color to List which is not possible, once you bind the data to your view you need to loop through all data item and set the color like below.

```
GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].BackColor = status ? System.Drawing.Color.Red : System.Drawing.Color.Green;
```